# Django: objects.all() exclude linked models

Tags: django

I have different models in Django linked together:
Projects
Fonts (linked by project_id)
Images (linked by project_id)
etc

When I'm using Project.objects.all() it retrieves all of the information from all the linked tables and query gets very slow. However in specific view I do not even need i.e. Fonts and Images. How can I tell django to skip these models while performing query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use values or values_list for this purpose. That way your queryset will only fetch the columns you want.

Using values

```
projects_obj = Project.objects.all().values('column_name', 'column_name')
```

Using values_list

```
projects_obj = Project.objects.all().values_list('column_name', 'column_name')
```

Comment: and If I specify all of the columns from table / model then It will not even query it? or it keeps querying but just does not return values?

Comment: If you want to use all columns then use normal queryset. This is only used when you don't want all columns but a specific type of data from the model